# VsCode debugger not hitting breakpoint if is not in the current file

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I would expect debugger to hit breakpoint regardless where the breakpoint is in the stack.

Having 2 files:

start.ts

```
import { transformString } from './Transform'
transformString('foo')
```

Transform.ts

```
export const transformNitroToClip = () => {
  // some code
  => my breakpoint
  // some code
}
```

With this configuration:

```
  {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Single File",
      "args": ["${relativeFile}"],
      "runtimeArgs": [
          "-r",
          "ts-node/register"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "outFiles": [ "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js" ]
  }
```

If I run the debugger in `start.ts` file I would expect the breakpoint from `Transform.ts` to be hit but it's not.

But if I put a debugger in `start.ts` to be hit first then the one from `Transform.ts` is hit as well.

Is there any workaround to not be required to have a debugger in the main file in order to trigger the other ones?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this behavior.  It looks like a race condition: I presume that the breakpoint cannot be set until `Transform.ts` is loaded, and once `Transform.ts` is loaded, VS Code is racing to set the breakpoint as the execution of the program continues.  If I change `start.ts` to:

```
import { transformString } from './Transform'
setTimeout(() => transformString('foo'), 100);
```

then everything works.  That might be an adequate workaround.

Consider commenting on [this issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/46).  I wonder if there is an API that `ts-node` can use to give the debugger time to install breakpoints after loading each TypeScript file.