# Typescript - ts-node vs compiling for development

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-node

New to typescript workflows. When working with node + JS, I usually have a `dev` script of the form: `nodemon index.js`. With typescript I see I have 2 options:

1. `nodemon --exec "ts-node index.ts"`
2. `concurrently "tsc -w" "nodemon -w dist dist/index.js"`

Which one is used more often in the typescript community? What are the implications?

Comment: I'm far from an expert on this subject, but I suspect you'll run into more problems and limitations with `ts-node`.  Here's just [one known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52778424) with `ts-node` that came up recently.